# Magento wishlist move to header

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm looking to move/include the wishlist into the header of my magento 1.7.1 install.

So far I've added:

layout/page.xml:

```
<block type="wishlist/customer_sidebar" name="wishlist_sidebar" as="mini_wishlist_top" after="cart_sidebar" template="wishlist/sidebar.phtml" />
```

Added to the:

```
<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">
```

block.

I've then added:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mini_wishlist_top'); ?>
```

into template/page/html/header.phtml

However this does not display anything on my store? am I missing something or do you need to be logged in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you added to the wrong template file.

Try adding

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mini_wishlist_top'); ?>`

to

`template/page/html/header.phtml`

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Sorry that is the header.phtml file I've added it too.

Comment: hm try putting `mini_wishlist_top` as block `name` as well, not only `as`

Comment: Same result, do I need to add something to the layout/wishlist.xml template?

Comment: no. can you post the code of your entire `<block type="page/html_header" name="header" as="header">...</block>`  part please?

Comment: Needed to be wishlist/links not wishlist/customer_sidebar for anyone else stuck.